# How can I get the exact number of lines in while read loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I used a while read loop in shell script to count and number line by line my file.txt. Now I want to give, inside the loop, the exact number of lines, like if I'm command wc -l. Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

  let count=0
  while read cdat ctim clat clon
       do
          h=${ctim:0:2};    # substring hours from ctim
          m=${ctim:3:2};
          s=${ctim:6:2};
          # echo $j
          if [[ $h>=11 ]]; then
              if [[ $h<=18 ]] && [[ $s<=00 ]]; then
                  if [[ $m != 01 ]]; then # spaces around "!=" is necessary
                      echo "$count $LINE" $cdat $ctim $clat $clon  
                      let count=$count+1
                  fi
              fi 
          fi
       done  <  cloud.txt 
  exit
```

And output contains lines like:

```
0  2014/04/00 14:44:00 26.12 -23.22
1  2014/11/21 16:05:00 19.56 -05.30
2  2014/01/31 13:55:00 02.00 31.10
3  2014/04/00 14:20:00 17.42 12.14
4  2014/07/25 15:30:00 35.25 05.90
5  2014/05/15 12:07:00 23.95 07.11
6  2014/07/29 17:34:00 44.00 17.43
7  2014/03/20 18:00:00 -11.12 -22.05
8  2014/09/21 12:00:00 06.44 41.55
```

My question is how to find that the output contains 9 lines?

Comment: What's wrong with `$count`?

Comment: Where in your output do you wish to see "9"? Before the 9 lines? After? Instead of?

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your specific question

```
      if [[ $h>=11 ]]; then
          if [[ $h<=18 ]] && [[ $s<=00 ]]; then
```

**All** of those tests **always return true**.

The `test`, `[` and `[[` commands act differently based on the number of arguments they see.
All those tests have 1 single argument. In that case, if it's a non-empty string, you have a success return code.

Crucial crucial crucial to put whitespace around the operators.

```
      if [[ $h >= 11 ]]; then
          if [[ $h <= 18 ]] && [[ $s <= 00 ]]; then
```

Question for you: what do you expect this test to do? `[[ $s <= 00 ]]`

Be aware that these are all *lexical* comparisions. You probably want this instead:

```
      # if hour is between 11 and 18 inclusive
      if (( 10#$h >= 11 && 10#$h <= 18 )); then
```

Comment: [[ $s <= 00 ]] is to stop just at 18h 00mn 00second. I expect to know how many lines are between 12h00mn00s and 18h00mn00s? Because the input file contains many lines between 00 and 23h.

Comment: Then you want: `if [[ $h >= 12 && $h <= 17 ]] || [[ $ctim == "18:00:00" ]]`

Comment: Exactly, I want to know how many lines are between 12:00:00 and 18:00:00?

Comment: Your condition : if [[ $h >= 12 && $h <= 17 ]] || [[ $ctim == "18:00:00" ]] has considerably reduced my if statements to   if [[ $h>=11 && $h<=17 ]] || [[ $ctim == "18:00:00" ]]; then
                      echo "$count $LINE" $cdat $ctim $clat $clon  
                      let count=$count+1
           fi
But now, it's till remaining that question how to include a command which can give me only the number of lines between 12:00:00 and 18:00:00? Like to print out only 9

Comment: If you want to start at 12:00, you can't have `[[ $h >= 11 ]]`. And, please please please, if there's one thing you get out of my answer, is that `[[ $h>=11 ]]` is **very** different from `[[ $h >= 11 ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You already know this value with $count. Since you're counting from 0, the number you want is $count+1.

Comment: Yes, but I want to add maybe a command inside my loop, which can only print out that number 9, to show only how many lines contain my output.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the command "wc -l" at the end of my loop, I can get exactly what I wanted, means that number of lines (9 lines). But I want to know if there is a way to get it exactly inside the loop, maybe using the same command "wc -l" or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

  let count=0
  while read cdat ctim clat clon
       do
          h=${ctim:0:2};    # substring hours from ctim
          m=${ctim:3:2};
          s=${ctim:6:2};
           if [[ $h>=11 && $h<=17 ]] || [[ $ctim == "18:00:00" ]]; then
               echo "$count $LINE" $cdat $ctim $clat $clon  
               let count=$count+1         
           fi

       done  <  cloud.txt | wc -l
```

exit

The result is exactly: **9**

But now how to do it inside the loop?